# what did those expressions do ii = (char *)&i ; aa= (char *)&a ; in the below program?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the concepts of pointer and i am stuck at this notation in line 6 and line 7 in the program. help me to understand this concept of pointer thanks in advance.
i am starting to learn basic of pointer in c and i am stuck with this expression

```
ii = (char *)&i;
aa= (char *)&a;
```

Full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i = 54; 
   float a = 3.14;
   char *ii , *aa; //declaring ii and aa as chaacter pointer
   ii = (char *)&i;
   aa= (char *)&a;
   printf("adress contained in ii = %u",ii);
   printf("adress contained in aa = %u",aa);
   printf("value at the adress contained in ii is %d " , *ii);
   printf("value at the adress contained in aa = %d ", *aa);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Is there more to it we aren't seeing?

Comment: What of the following do you know/understand: effect of operator `&`, effect of "cast" `(char*)`. That info is needed to gauge your level of knowledge and make a suitable answer.

Comment: The reason for the cast is because the variable is a different data type from the pointer.

Comment: The question as is asks for a pointer tutorial and is hence too broad. Please give more details of what you want explained and of what you already know. Then the question can be focused enough.

Comment: Please learn [ask]. What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: `%p` and `(void *)` casts instead of `%u` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `&i` yields a value of type `int *` (pointer to `int`), which is the address of `i`.  Similarly, `&a` yields a value of type `double *` (pointer to `double`).

With the exception of the `void *` type, C does not allow you to assign pointer values of one type to an object of a different pointer type - IOW, you can't assign a `int *` or a `double *` value to a `char *` object directly.  You must use a *cast expression* to tell the compiler to treat the value as a different type:

```
ii = (char *) &i;
```

means "treat the result of `&i` as a pointer to `char` and assign the result to `ii`".  The `(char *)` expression is a *cast*, and it tells the compiler to treat the value of the following expression as that type.

So, why would you want to do this?

Except for bitfields, any object can be mapped onto an array of `char` or `unsigned char` - IOW, the integer value `0x01234567` can be treated as the array of `char` values `{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67}`.  You can use this property perform some useful tests, or to determine how certain values are being represented.  For example, if you want to know if your system is big- or little-endian, you can take the `int` value `0x00000001`, treat it as an array of `char`, and test the 0'th and last elements:

```
int val = 0x00000001;        // assumes 32-bit integers!
char *varr = (char *) &val;  // pretends val is an array of char

if ( varr[0] == 0x01 )
  // little endian
else if ( varr[ sizeof val - 1 ] == 0x01 )
  // big endian
else
  // something else
```

Note that casting pointer values to different types isn't necessarily *safe* - you can enable some truly nasty bugs by doing this.